# Construct a $C^1$ function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ with prescribed rank

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Construct a $C^1$ function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that rank of $D(F)$ has rank $2$, except at the origin where it has rank $1$.

I'm having trouble constructing such a function. Actually it looks like a blind guess to me. Can anyone show me how to think of constructing such a function? What does the change of rank mean near the origin? I'm guessing it has something to do with diffeomorphism.

Comment: Can you think of examples of $2 \times 2$ matrices which have rank 1 or rank 2? That might be a place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think about it geometrically: $f(x,y):\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is a change of coordinates on the plane. The determinant of $Df$ measures how the area of an infinitesimal square at that point changes when it is mapped to an infinitesimal parallelogram by $f$.

$Df$ has full rank if the area is nonzero. So visualizing $f$, you want it to map a checkerboard on the plane to a "curved" checkerboard where the area of the cells decreases to zero (only) at the origin.

That still leaves ensuring that $Df$ has rank one, and not zero, at the origin. The geometric interpretation here is that you want just one, and not both, of the cell boundary curves to shrink to zero length as you approach the origin.

For example, if you could find a function that maps a checkerboard on the plane to the following, you'd be in business:

[image]

Can you think of a function $f$ that can do that?

Comment: Thanks so much for such a great answer! So f(a,b)=(a*cos(b),a*sin(b)) should do it?

Comment: but doesn't it have rank 0? I'm sorry but can you give a example of it...

Comment: It has rank one. $Df(a,b) = \left[\begin{array}{cc}\cos b & \sin b\\-a\sin b & a\cos b\end{array}\right]$, what do you get when you plug in $0,0$?

Comment: my bad... I just realized but when I wanted to delete it, you already responded..Thank you for being patient.